# Files (.CS) not appearing in custom nuget package as editable, adding the files with <files> causes duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, nuget, nuget-package

perhaps I am going in the wrong direction with this, but any advice would be appreciated. I am trying to develop a small nuget package which can be installed into new .NET Framework Web Apps (MVC) so that new projects can start quicker, quickly adding features such as SSO, Areas, and business logic etc.

This then needs to be extendable so once the package is installed, the routes, areas, and auth can all be built upon.

The package works fine, it can be installed into a new project and all the auth, styling and routes work fine. The problem is these installed features appear to be hidden away within the .dll or the bin of the package, and I'm seemingly not able to edit them.

I tried adding some extra details in the csproj, and/or the .nuspec manifest, to manually pushing the files into the projects file structure. Unfortunately this just seems to create duplicates on top of the files encased in the nugets .dll and causes build errors.

Is it possible to actually have editable .cs files in nuget packages which can be accessed by the user, or am I overstepping the goal of this package?

See below my .nuspec manifest.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<package >
  <metadata>
    <id>$id$</id>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <title>$title$</title>
    <authors>$author$</authors>
    <requireLicenseAcceptance>false</requireLicenseAcceptance>
    <license type="expression">MIT</license>
    <!-- <icon>icon.png</icon> -->
    <description>$description$</description>
    <releaseNotes>Initial Release</releaseNotes>
    <copyright>$copyright$</copyright>
    <tags>x</tags>
    <dependencies>
            <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.8">
                <dependency id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" />
                <dependency id="bootstrap" version="5.1.3" />
                <dependency id="jQuery" version="3.6.0"  />
                <dependency id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.19.4"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.9"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.9" />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.9"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="3.6.0"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Abstractions" version="6.20.0"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.JsonWebTokens" version="6.20.0" />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Logging" version="6.20.0"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols" version="6.20.0"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" version="6.20.0"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" version="6.20.0"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.12"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin" version="4.2.2"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb" version="4.2.2" />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Security" version="4.2.2" />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies" version="4.2.2" />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.Owin.Security.OpenIdConnect" version="4.2.2"  />
                <dependency id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="2.0.0"  />
                <dependency id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" />
                <dependency id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="13.0.1" />
                <dependency id="Owin" version="1.0"  />
                <dependency id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="6.20.0" />
                <dependency id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0"  />
            </group>
        </dependencies>
  </metadata>
    <files>
      <file src="Areas\Admin\AdminAreaRegistration.cs" target="content\Areas\Admin\" />
      <file src="App_Start\Startup.Auth.cs" target="content\App_Start\" />
      <file src="Areas\Admin\Controllers\AdmiNController.cs" target="content\Areas\Admin\Controllers\" />
    </files>
</package>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible because NuGets are already **COMPILED CODE**.

also, NuGet's goal is to package reusable code and really not make them editable.

What you are probably looking for is Source Generators .NET SDK

Comment: As i thought then! Thanks for taking the time to respond!